# Cygwin content disappear issue

Tags: cygwin, android-ndk

I am working on an Android App and just start to use Cygwin for ndk-build. When I build my c lib, the output may disappear while scrolling down fast. The same will happen when I try to make other libraries based on Linux through Cygwin. Although I can reopen the cmd window and make the project again to see the output that really matters, such as, warnings, errors, but it's really annoying to do it again and again.

Does someone encounter the same question? How to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What terminal are you using? By default cygwin just runs bash under the usual windows cmd.exe, which is definitely not all that great; installing and using mintty (simplest way to do so is through cygwin's setup.exe) and setting the scrollback buffer size to accommodate your needs should fix the problem.

You could use other terminals too- PuTTY, xterm, rxvt, etc (even the KDE and Gnome terminals are available through [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/))- but mintty is probably the best option for most cygwin users' needs (it's rather simple, small, and fast, and it integrates well with Windows).

Another option would be to redirect compilation messages: use > to redirect stdout to a file, overwriting it if it already exists, >> to append, and add a & if you want both stdout and stderr redirected, e.g. `gcc mysource.c &>compilelog`.

Comment: Further to the redirecting tip, you can use the `tee` tool to send the output to a file for later reference yet still have it shown live, like so: `make |& tee make.log`

Comment: Ah, and a bit of pedantry: Cygwin bash doesn't run in cmd.exe, but in a Windows console window, which Windows automatically creates for programs that need one. Cmd.exe is just another program running in a console window. You can run cmd.exe in mintty too, albeit not very well.